# How do I use a Visual Studio 2010 Project Template I created

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates

I followed the [steps on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) for creating a template. I created a new project in VS2010 and then used the *File->Export Template...* option to create my template. I went through the wizard and everything seemed to make sense. I left the default Output location alone (it was:

...Documents\Visual Studio 2010\My Exported Templates\MyProject.zip)

and I left the *Automatically import the template into Visual Studio* checked. I can see the exported zip file (and I tried moving a copy to the:

Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#

folder. But when I start up a new instance of VS2010 and use *File->New Project* I don't see my template. I was expecting that in addition to **RecentTemplates/ Installed Templates/ Online Templates** I might get a new category for **User Templates**. Failing that I thought it might be under Installed Templates but there is nothing new there. Where is my template supposed to appear? Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Duh, It was working I just didn't know where to look. I would bring up the new project template and search through all the leaf nodes. Turns out I had to click on the Visual C# root in the tree view (it appears to not be in any of the leafs). This always trips me up in tree views, I never expect the root to have options, let alone be the only place that has an option. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should restart( quit and run again) your visual studio!

Comment: I discovered what I was doing wrong and posted it as the answer about 5 months ago.

Comment: If you edit the VSTemplate file, you can change the ProjectSubType to "Web" to put it into the Web section.  Just match the ProjectSubType to the proper name of the section you want it to appear in.