# Game development in OGRE C++

Tags: c++, game-engine, ogre

I had successfully compiled and run the tutorial mentioned at `ogre3d.org`. It compiles without any error.

In that tutorial i used http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting%2BUp%2BAn%2BApplication%2B-%2BVisual%2BStudio to setup OGRE in visual studio 2010. I used a tutorialframework mentioned in that. I had changed the configuration properties when setting up `OGRE project`.

My Questions are:

1. Do i need to change configuration properties for all projects?
2. Why did `Tutorialframework` used in tutorial?
3. What files i need when starting a new project in `OGRE`?

Comment: Just want to make sure you realize the distinction that OGRE is a [3D rendering engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_%28computer_graphics%29), not a full [game engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_engine) (a rendering engine is one component of a game engine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Think of it like the skeleton to your application. Every single tutorial application uses the same properties; even load the config with the same name (unless you change it)
3. Once you go through all the [tutorials](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Tutorials) and understand how OGRE operates, you will understand what files you need.

Comment: Is there a way to copy configuration property to another project of same type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386098/visual-studio-can-i-copy-a-projects-properties-to-use-in-another-project