# Export an project setting from visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have created a project under an solution. I have set up all boost libs and some other project properties such as code generation.

Now I want to create another project and use the same settings. How can I reuse all the settings i have just used in this project in  another project

I found another solution which involves property sheets:

[Visual Studio: can I copy a project's properties to use in another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386098/visual-studio-can-i-copy-a-projects-properties-to-use-in-another-project)

While in that case I need to create and setup the property sheet. Isn't there an simple solution like export and import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no import/export fuctionality (probably because property sheets exist).

Simple way: copy the project file, rename it, open it in a text editor and change the `ProjectGuid` (just modifying a single char/digit should be fine) and `RootNamespace` to match your new project name. New project, same settings.

Proper way: if you would have made your original changes to property sheets in the first place, you'd already have everything needed and could simply re-use those property sheets in any new project. So you could just start over now and create a new project, add a property sheets for boost stuff, another one for compiler/linker settings and so on (multiple property sheets is a good thing, as the can be combined in a modular way at will). Or you can create a new project, add property sheet and open it in a text editor side-by-side with your current project and just copy-paste the settings you altered.= to the property sheet.