# Hosting Custom Visual studio template locally

Tags: visual-studio

The online templates shown in visual studio are from my understanding downloaded from Visual Studio Marketplace. Is there a possibility to host my "own" marketplace where other developers in my company can access the Project Templates I publish without doing this available to people outside my company?

[image]

Comment: Your own marketplace can simply be a shared folder your team can access, the templates can be exported to zip-files. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381941/how-can-i-load-a-template-i-have-created-in-visual-studio

Comment: Okay, so each developer has to import these templates everytime they are changed? I'd wish vsts had support for such a feature..

Comment: Hmm there is a setting (Projects and solutions / Locations) that allows you to change users project templates folder location, maybe you can use that so that those will be fetched from a shared folder? Haven't used this myself so I haven't tested that.