# Importing project settings (properties) across projects in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386098/visual-studio-can-i-copy-a-projects-properties-to-use-in-another-project) one. But, when going to the properties manager ("View > Other Windows > Property Manager"):

[image: properties1]

and selecting "Add New Project Property Sheet...":

[image: properties2]

the property files is exported but its contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup />
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

Where are the build flags set (I need a custom build with optimizations, incremental linking, aslr and dep all disabled)? These custom settings are present in the above figure in project "ExampleSubroutine1" and I want to make use of them, also in project "SingleLocalVariable", but importing the properties file in "SingleLocalVariable" does not set the respective build flags.

Why?

The following settings are present in "ExampleSubroutine1":

[image: properties3]

while defaults are kept in "SingleLocalVariable" even though I've imported the properties sheet from "ExampleSubroutine1":

[image: properties4]

I am using the same build configuration for all projects (Debug x64):

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the same property sheet is added for "SingleLocalVariable" too for Debug|x64 configuration ? Check using Property Manager.

Comment: Yes, I only have the Debug x64 configuration for all projects.

Comment: You have to check Property Manager, not Configuration Manager.