# Is there any free tool out there to simply duplicate a Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, project, code-duplication

I am aware of the manual procedure presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884255/visual-studio-copy-project) and of this commercial [product](http://www.kinook.com/CopyWiz/), but I am wondering if you know a (free) Visual Studio extension (e.g. allowing project copy/paste) or standalone tool that can properly duplicate a project (with new assembly IDs, name etc).

Thanks!

Comment: Copy and changing the ID seems simple.  Do you have to do it very often where tools and automation are warranted?  Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Not often I must say, but I would appreciate a copy/paste shortcut to do it when needed.