# Go to definition in copied solution searching in original solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, qt5

I'm breaking a QT5 project into two separated ones. I've copied the source code and Qt Project (.pro) and imported it again to a new Visual Studio solution.

Now when I "go to definition" or "find all references" it finds also the old solution files. I would like to search only within my current solution.

**Edit**: QT version is 5.6.0, Visual Studio is 2015 Community, and I'm using a QT plugin found on Tools > Extensions and Updates > Qt5Package.

**Edit2:** Using the search it's possible to search only within the current solution or file. But I would rather like, if possible, to correct the F12 and Shift-F12 functions, so they only point to the correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closing and opening again Visual Studio, it works properly. Just reopening the solution didn't seem to help.

Comment: So now I realize that what probably solved it was changing the name of the new solution. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884255/visual-studio-copy-project).