# How to install packages in all future projects without downloading in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

In Visual Studio how can I avoid having to download a package like entity framework each time I create a new project?

Comment: You cannot, unless all projects are using package references. When package references are used, NuGet packages are downloaded only once and saved to a cache for your logon account.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that might work for you is to create a project exactly as you want it and keep it as a template, or you could also copy that project to start a new project instead of starting from scratch.  See this SO post [Visual Studio Copy Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884255/visual-studio-copy-project).  The marked answer speaks to copying, but one of the other posts speaks about templates and might give you a starting point.

It would be nice if you could run a script inside the package manager, but I have never found a source that directly explains how to do that.  Perhaps another user could add that to this thread if they know how to do that.

Comment: You can test that out yourself. I don't think it would work if `packages.config` is used.

Comment: @LexLi just to clarify for me, which part in my answer are you referring to for testing?

Comment: If your project template uses `packages.config`, then every time creating a project from it would lead to the downloads of NuGet packages, as NuGet cache is per solution in that case. Thus, your answer is not 100% correct.

Comment: @LexLi Got it.  Thx.  But the template or copy process, my primary suggestion, should work for the ops request, yes?

Comment: Probably, but I don't think using a custom template is **a must**. As long as package reference is used, NuGet cache is per logon account, which can significantly reduce the downloads from NuGet.org.