# How can I merge Asp.net core SPA (Single page Application) and Asp.net core Web Application into a seperate project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have two separate projects in solution folder:
 Project A.) SPA (based on Asp.net core 2.0).
 Project B.) Asp.net core Web Application.

I want them merged into a single project.
I tried to put "Project A" into area section in newly created project (Asp.net core Web Application) but that did not work.
What will be the work around for this problem. Sorry for any grammatical mistake.

Comment: what did you achieve so far?

Comment: Do you want to merge then or do you want them to copy in another solution? Maybe this will help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884255/visual-studio-copy-project)

Comment: @gagro the link is not helpful so far.